# How to fetch data in Swipe refresh layout fro server

Tags: android

I am fetching data from server in recycler view. I am trying to implement Swipe refresh to fetch updated data on server.
But when I refresh It fetches latest data from server but not replace the old data in recycler view due to which I have duplicate data in recycler view both old and latest data.Everytime I refresh data copies in recycler view.

This my code below:

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".Home"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/linearHome"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
android:paddingBottom="16dp">  

 <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/refresh">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycle"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Home.java**

```
public class Home extends Fragment {

RecyclerView recycle;
ArrayList<LoadHomeBooks> list;
SwipeRefreshLayout refresh;

private static final String URL = "https://www.example.com"

public Home() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    recycle = view.findViewById(R.id.recycle);
    refresh = view.findViewById(R.id.refresh);

    list = new ArrayList<>();

    recycle.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recycle.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    loadData();

    refresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {

           loadData();
        }
    }); 

    return view;

  } 

} 

 private void loadData(){

     OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(22, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(22, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(22, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder().add("city", myValue).build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(URL).post(formBody).build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {

                if (getActivity() != null) {

                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            try {

                                prog.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                                if (jsonArray.length() == 0) {

                                    nobook.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }

                                for (int i = jsonArray.length() - 1; i > -1; i--) {

                                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String str1 = jsonObject.getString("Book_name");

                                    LoadHomeBooks model = new LoadHomeBooks(str1);

                                    list.add(model);
                                }

                               HomeBookAdapter adapter = new HomeBookAdapter(listist, getContext());

                                recycle.setAdapter(adapter);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, final IOException e) {

                if (getActivity() != null) {

                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            TastyToast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.ERROR).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        });
 }
```

Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: You need to clear your list by `list.clear()` before adding data before `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Change your setOnRefreshListener to this:

```
refresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
               list.clear();
               loadData();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to update or clear/Reset the recycle view please implement below method in your adapter

```
public void updateData(List<LoadHomeBooks> listNew, int flag) {
        if (flag == 0) { //append
            for (int i = 0; i < listNew.size(); i++) {
                yourListInAddapter.add(listNew.get(i));
                notifyItemInserted(getItemCount());
            }
            //notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else { //clear all
            yourListInAddapter.clear();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

when you need to clear/Reset recycle view call this

```
yourAddapter.updateData(null, 1);
```

When you need to append items to recycle view call this

```
yourAddapter.updateData(newList, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DiffUtlis for this. add this function in your adapter.

```
fun receive(l: ArrayList<DaoModel>) {
    val result = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(MyDiffUtils(listOfItems, l))
    listOfItems.clear()
    listOfItems.addAll(l)
    result.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
}
```

and OnSwipeRefreshListener call this method

```
adapter.receive(list)
```

and here is the DiffUtils

```
class MyDiffUtils(private val oldList: MutableList<DaoModel>, private val newList: List<DaoModel>) :
DiffUtil.Callback() {
override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
    return oldList[oldItemPosition].Id == newList[newItemPosition].Id
}

override fun getOldListSize(): Int {
    return oldList.size
}

override fun getNewListSize(): Int {
    return newList.size
}

override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
    return oldList[oldItemPosition] == newList[newItemPosition]
}}
```